# Are there any contraindications for using laptop vertically?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I'm planning to purchase a separate monitor for using with laptop (lenovo e520) but due to lack of space on the desk I'm going to put laptop into a vertical position with closed lid.

Is there any reason it can harm the laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's rated to run with closed lid, and you don't block the vents, no.